# Apache HttpClient5 ignores any configuration

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-5.x

I'm trying to contact a https server with a self-signed certificate in a unit test. Because of local development vs CI issues it would be easiest to just blindly accept the self-signed certificate.

It seems I'm forced to use Apache HttpClient 5 and can't downgrade to 4.

This is my configuration:

```
  public HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory getHttpClientFactory()
      throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
      KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException {

    var httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManagerBuilder.create()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactoryBuilder.create()
                .setSslContext(SSLContextBuilder.create()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(TrustAllStrategy.INSTANCE)
                    .build())
                .setHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE)
                .build())
            .build())
        .build();

    var requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
    requestFactory.setHttpClient(httpClient);
    return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory();
  }
```

This however seems to be completely ignored. Before either `TrustStrategy.isTrusted` or `HostnameVerifier.verify` are called (checked with both breakpoints and my own implementation) I get an exception `sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException` `PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Here is the client code

```
        var template = new RestTemplate(getHttpClientFactory());
        template.exchange("https://127.0.0.1:8080/", HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
        client = new ApiClient(template);
```

the second line is just for quicked debugging, when I remove it then it crashed on later usage of client. ApiClient is swagger generated code, but as it already crashes in the second line this seems unimportant to the question.

I also tried to use a custom DnsResolver to fix the subject name so that the subject name in the certificate is right in any environment, but that, too, is completely ignored. The stacktrace goes of into sun.security without ever calling any of the configuration objects.

this is the include from my pom.xml

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Do I need some other dependency or configuration to make it work?

I tried differrent TrustStrategy and HostnameVerifier implementations that are all ignored as well as different workarounds to get the self-signed cert to work, but the difference between dev systems and CI is too big.

Comment: You aren't using any of theat. You are creating a `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` and then ignore all of what you have done before and do `return new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory()`. With that you basically made all what comes before useless. You should do, probably, `return requestFactory`.

Comment: Ah, I feel stupid now, thanks for the hint X_X